# Selecting different columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select different columns in a pandas dataframe using selection key

Let us say my dataframe is,

```
import pandas as pnd
s1 = pnd.Series ([0,3,6,7])
s2 = pnd.Series ([1,4,8,9])
s3 = pnd.Series ([2,5,10,11])
df = pnd.DataFrame({'A':s1, 'B':s2, 'C':s3})

   A  B   C
0  0  1   2
1  3  4   5
2  6  8  10
3  7  9  11
```

and my selection key is,

```
s4 = pnd.Series (['A','B','C','A'])


0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
```

My desired result is,

```
0  0
1  4
2  10
3  7
```

I guess I could run a for loop to do this

```
l = []
for idx in df.index:
    l.append( df[s4[idx]][idx])
s5 = pnd.Series(l)
print s5
```

Is there a better/shorter/more efficient way?

Comment: `df.stack().ix[zip(s4.index, s4)]` ?, but you'll get a multi level index, not sure if that's OK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pnd.Series(df.lookup(df.index, s4), df.index)
```